# Then returns too early most of the time on angularFire's $bind promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm looking to perform an action once the data comes back from firebase by using then on the promise returned from $bind. However, when using $bind to create a promise most of the time the "then" function will run before the data is returned from firebase.

Multiple $binds will result in only the first "then" running after the data is back from firebase but this is only the case if I'm not binding to an object.

The "then" that runs on a $bind on an object in firebase never seems to return after the data is available.

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['firebase'])
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebase',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $firebase) {


  // Data 1
  // The first bind's then will fire correctly
  $scope.data1 = $firebase(new Firebase("https://bindTest.firebaseio.com/users/1/email"));
  $scope.data1.$bind($scope, "data1Remote").then(function() {
    console.log("data1Remote: then");
    console.log($scope.data1Remote);
    $scope.data1RemoteThen = angular.copy($scope.data1Remote);
  });
  console.log("data1Remote: not then");
  console.log($scope.data1Remote);


  // Data 2
  // The then function doesn't seem to work at all if it references an object
  $scope.data2 = $firebase(new Firebase("https://bindTest.firebaseio.com/users/1"));
  $scope.data2.$bind($scope, "data2Remote").then(function() {
    console.log("data2Remote: then");
    console.log($scope.data2Remote);
    $scope.data2RemoteThen = angular.copy($scope.data2Remote);
  });
  console.log("data1Remote: not then");
  console.log($scope.data1Remote);


  // Data 3
  // Since this section follows another bind the then doesn't work.
  $scope.data3 = $firebase(new Firebase("https://bindTest.firebaseio.com/syncedValue"));
  $scope.data3.$bind($scope, "data3Remote").then(function() {
    console.log("data3Remote: then");
    console.log($scope.data3Remote);
    $scope.data3RemoteThen = angular.copy($scope.data3Remote);
  });
  console.log("data2Remote: not then");
  console.log($scope.data1Remote);

}
  ]);
```

Unless I'm missing something the "then" function should only run after firebase has bound its data to the scope. I have created a Plunker that illustrates this issue. Try commenting out the different data sections in different combinations and you will notice that the "thens" that return correctly change as well.  Has anyone else experienced / found a solution to this issue?  Thanks.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9UgDxx?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a bug.  I reported it and Anant fixed it super fast.  Awesome.  The fix is applied to the master branch of the angularFire github.

Comment: The fix will go out with AngularFire v0.6.0 - thanks for reporting it!